# How do I tell a class method to wait until a signal from a QDialog class method is caught?

Tags: python, multithreading, qt, pyqt, pyside

I have the following code:

```
class Functions(QObject):

    mysig = Signal(filename)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Functions, self).__init__(parent)
        self.result = None

    def showDialog(self, filename):
        self.mysig.emit(filename)

    def grabResult(self):

        while not self.result:
            time.sleep(5)

        return result #this is the question

    def setResult(self, result):
        self.result = result
```

The other part of the code has this:

```
class Dialog(QDialog):

    anotherSig = Signal(str)
    fun = Functions()

    def __init__(self, parent=None, filename=filename):
        self.filename = filename
        #Here it displays a picture based on the filename parameter

    def okButtonClicked(self):
        text = self.lineedit.text()
        fun.setResult(text)
        #Tried also this:
        self.anotherSig.emit(text)
```

The `Functions()` class is called from a worker `QThread` (not shown here).

I guess my question is this: how do I tell my `Functions` class that the user has entered the the text and clicked the OK button? I tried connecting that `anotherSig` Signal, but when I try to do so, Qt complains about QPixmaps not being safe to be set from a different thread, and it doesn't work.

The method that I am using here "works", but I feel it's not very reliable. Plus, it only works when all of the relevant methods in the `Functions` class are `@classmethod` - this way, for some reason, it doesn't work. The `setResult` is called (I added a `print` statement to make sure), but the `grabResult` still shows `self.result` as `None`.

Comment: can you add the code for how you are setting up the threading?  I suspect that the details of that are related to your problem.  Which thread(s) do you think all of this stuff is happening on?

Comment: http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong/ this link might also be relevant.

Comment: The thread code is very simple. It executes some completely unrelated task, and that makes a call `self.fun.showDialog(filename)`, where `self.fun` is `Functions()`. 

I don't see how that could be related to this problem. The `Functions()` class is executed from that QThread, however, that part works just fine. Executing the `Dialog` class works. My question is how to send a variable from the `Dialog` class back to my `Functions()` class.

Comment: I ask about the threading because of your comment about QPixmaps and cross-thread errors, so what thread various bits of code are running on is relevant.  If you can replace you function call to `showDialog` with a signal/slot you might get rid of the QPixmap thread issue.

Comment: I have tried that, way back, and it didn't work. Well, it worked at the same level as it does now - I was not able to communicate from the QDialog class to the Functions class. Though you are right there wasn't the QPixmap warning. No (huge) deal, QPixmap is just a warning and I've fixed that. The question remains how to send a variable from the QDialog to the Functions class.

Comment: on further consideration, where is the QPixmap in this?

Comment: can you add the code that `mysig` is connected to?

Answer (score 0):

This code is not working because the call to `showDialog` is happening on the instantiation of a `Functions` object that is an attribute of what ever object is off on the other thread.  Your `fun` in `Dialog`, which you set the result on, is a different instantiation.

To move the results back to the original `Functions` object I think you need to connect `anotherSig` of the `Dialog` object to the `setResult` function on the `Functions` object you want to get the results back.

Does something like this work (hard to test this with out a good bit of boiler plate).

```
class Functions(QObject):

    mysig = Signal(filename,Functions)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Functions, self).__init__(parent)
        self.result = None

    def showDialog(self, filename):
        self.mysig.emit(filename,self)

    def grabResult(self):

        while not self.result:
            time.sleep(5)

        return result #this is the question

    @QtCore.Slot(str)
    def setResult(self, result):
        self.result = result

def connection_fun(filename,fun):
    d = Dialog(filename)
    # what ever else you do in here
    d.anotherSig.connect(fun.setResult))
```

Comment: The problem is (I think) in the following (and this kind of answers the last comment you made on my OP): in order for the QDialog to execute, I need to tell the main GUI thread to execute it. Without it, Qt complains about GUI not being executed from the GUI thread.

So the `self.mysig.emit` signal is connected to in the MainGUI class, which then does the `Dialog(filename).exec_()` - and then the dialog shows. I'll try this, passing an object as a parameter (good idea), but then what do I do with that object in the QDialog?

Comment: nothing.  All of the connection logic is taken care of for you behind the scenes by Qt.  When `d` emits `anotherSig` the string is passed to the `setResult` function of the `Functions` object you want the data to get back to.  You can remove `fun` from `Dialog` as it does not need to know anything about where it is passing the string to.

Comment: Oh I have tried this as well. Tried connecting the signal from Dialog to the slot in the Functions object in the main GUI thread, like you suggested. Results? Unfortunately, with this, python.exe stops responding and the whole application crashes.

Comment: I think to say anything else sensible, we would need to see more of your code and how it is all connected together.  What thread is `grabResults` running on?  If it is on the same thread as `setResult` it will dead-lock. (which brings this back to really being a threading issue).

Answer (score 0):

Using `time.sleep` causes your application to freeze. One method for making your class wait is using `QEventLoop` like this:

```
loop = QEventLoop()
myDialog.mySignal.connect(loop.quit)
loop.exec_()
```